# Matlab: Creating new vector after comparing two vectors

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors A and B.

```
A = [-1; 2; 4; 2; 4];
B = [1; 2; 14; 0; -4];
```

I want to do elementwise comparision of above two vectors and obtain a third vector:

```
C =[1; 0; 1; -1; -1];
```

i.e.

```
C(i) = -1 if B(i) < A(i)
C(i) = +1 if B(i) > A(i)
C(i) = 0 if B(i) = A(i)
```

My Solution:

```
C = A - B;
C(C>0) = 1;
C(C<0) = -1
C(C==0) = 0;
```

Any better method is appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [sign](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) function

```
C = sign(B - A)
```

Result

```
C =

   1
   0
   1
  -1
  -1
```

Comment: Oops, apologies for the edit - I was following the code at the end of the question, rather than the specifications earlier on.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it useful to define a function `vif` (vectorized if) as

```
function res = vif(test, a, b)

  res = zeros(size(test));

  if isscalar(a); a = repmat(a, size(test)); end
  if isscalar(b); b = repmat(b, size(test)); end

  res(test)  = a(test);
  res(~test) = b(~test);

end
```

You would then be able to write

```
>> C = vif(A>B, 1, vif(A<B, -1, 0));
```

The nested calls to `vif` work like a nested `if` statement, or a sequence of `if` and `elseif` statements, a la

```
if A > B
  C = 1;
else
  if A < B
    C = -1;
  else
    C = 0;
  end
end
```

or

```
if A > B
  C = 1;
elseif A < B
  C = -1;
else
  C = 0;
end
```

It's a bit more involved than using the `sign` function as suggested in another answer, but is much more flexible - you can assign arbitrary values to the true and false branches, and each branch can either be a vector or a scalar.